why is the timeout exception not thrown here in my python script?
I am using python 3.10.15 on a Mac
I have the following code
def send_prediction_request2(self, request_id: str, timeout) -> dict:
    url = self.baseUrl + self.analysis_endpoint
    logger.info(f'About to call {url} for request id {request_id}')

    try:
        duration = Chronometer()
        headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.token}
        r = requests.post(url, data=self.payload, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
        logger.info(f'Response received from {url} for request id {request_id} with status code {r.status_code} '
                    f'with timeout of {timeout} and response time is {duration.time_spent()}')
        r.raise_for_status()
        return r.json()

    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        logger.error(f'call to {url} timedout after {timeout} seconds with the exception of {str(e)}')
        raise
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        logger.error(f'call to {url}  failed: {str(e)}')
        raise

I have the timeout that gets passed in as (2,2) 2 seconds for connect and 2 seconds for read.
There are calls that take over 2 seconds for connection time and the exceptions never got thrown.
I can pass in a timeout of (int) of 20 seconds and there are calls that take over 20 seconds and no exception get thrown.
am i coding the timeout and exception handling incorrectly?
Is my understanding of the time incorrect?

could this be an issue?
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#timeouts
Note
The connect timeout applies to each connection attempt to an IP address. If multiple addresses exist for a domain name, the underlying urllib3 will try each address sequentially until one successfully connects. This may lead to an effective total connection timeout multiple times longer than the specified time, e.g. an unresponsive server having both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses will have its perceived timeout doubled, so take that into account when setting the connection timeout.

I would suspect the timeout is if the connection's data stream stalls. As long as data is trickling in (or in your case, sending up), the read timeout gets reset every time the underlying socket reads or writes data.
